# How to make new file with date in it?

Tags: command-line, date

I can create a new file and put the date in it.

```
touch example.txt
date >> example.txt
```

But I must create the file with the date in it the moment I created the new file.
How do I do that with only one command?

Comment: `touch` updates the modification time of a file, or creates the file if it does not exist. Since the file would be created with the redirection `>>` or `>` anyway, this command is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 15):

Simply use the date command to redirect into file and it will be created:

```
date > example.txt
```

A prefered way would using the `>>` append operator:

```
date >> example.txt
```

Both the redirection operator (`>`) and the append operator (`>>`) will create the target file if it doesn't exist. You never need to create it first and write to it later.

Comment: Note that `>` will *clear* the file if it *does* exist, whereas `>>` as in the OP's original sequence will add the date to the end of the file if it already exists.

Comment: I know that and the edit by terdon has clearly stated this!

Comment: The edit does not seem clear in that aspect to me. I just thought it's worth mentioning because even though the OP asks about creating a new file, their existing sequence will not destroy the data in an existing file if something goes wrong.

Comment: Note that OP said "create file at the same time" so it's a new file that needs a date entry before use so `>` should be enough!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I prefer `>>` when I know the file is not supposed to exist. It's easier to recover from a mistaken use of `>>` than to recover from a mistaken use of `>`.

Comment: Updated my answer @kasperd and Random832 to refelect best practice...

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that, if the problem with

> I must create the file with the date in it the moment I created the new file

is due to race conditions (e.g. there's a process periodically scanning for a file with that name, and expects to find a date in there), even doing

```
date > example.txt
```

isn't correct, as there's still a very small window between when the shell opens the file and when `date` actually writes its stuff (which may also be written non-atomically as well).

In that case, the solution is to write to a separate file *and then* perform a `mv` to the correct file name:

```
date > example.txt.tmp
mv example.txt.tmp example.txt
```

A move on the same file system is guaranteed to be atomic, so when `example.txt` appears, it already contains the expected content.

---

If instead the question is just about typing a single command, the original solution is of course the correct and most straightforward one.

Comment: The `date > ...` still isn't atomic, so that additional `mv` step still doesn't help the race condition. Example: `date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S.%N > foo && stat foo && cat foo`.

Comment: @ckujau: I don't see what's your point... of course `date > ...` isn't atomic - I even said that ("which may also be written non-atomically as well"). The rename of course is effective only if the other program looks specifically for the final filename, not just any file in the directory.